# Web Socket upload file and send json on the same endpoint

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using Jetty to implement JSR-356 Web socket for chat application.
For managed conversations and sending different message types I'm using DTO object which are serialized from/to json using Jackson and TextDecoder

```
public class JsonDtoCodec implements Decoder.Text<Dto>,Encoder.Text<Dto>{
        ObjectMapper om = ... //some object mapper

        @Override
        public Dto decode(String json) throws DecodeException {
            Dto dto = null;
            try {
                dto = om.readValue(json,Dto.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //ToDo add Log
            }
            return dto;
        }

        @Override
        public String encode(Dto dto) throws EncodeException {
            try {
                return om.writeValueAsString(dto);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, In my endpoint I'm using direct Dto objects:

```
    @ServerEndpoint(value = "/{version}/{userType}/{token}",
            decoders =JsonDtoCodec.class,
            encoders = JsonDtoCodec.class)
    public class ChatServerEndPoint {

     @OnMessage
        public void onMessage(final @PathParam("userType") String userType,
                              final @PathParam("token") String token,
                              final @PathParam("version") String version,
                              final Session session,
                              Dto dto)
                throws IOException {

               //handling all DTO related object and sending response
               Dto response = .... // create some DTO
               session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(dto);

    } 
}
```

Unfortunately, I need to handle uploading image files through web socket up to 100Kb size.

Can I use the same endpoint for handling both, DTOs and Binary Data?
If not should I add new EndPoint and should I handle two separate connections one for binaries and one for Json content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly can.

You would have 2 `@OnMessage` annotated methods. (one handling TEXT, the other BINARY)

Assuming that your `JsonToDtoCodec` extends `Decoder.Text<Dto>`, then your other method would be declared as ...

```java
@OnMessage(maxMessageSize=100000)
public void onFileUpload(final Session session, final ByteBuffer buf)
{
}
```

Since you said the files would be a maximum of 100kb, then having the method pass in the complete `ByteBuffer` is sufficient.  If it were larger, you could use an InputStream approach instead.  As for limiting the size of that buffer, your `maxMessageSize` annotation would keep that sane.

Note: if a client attempts to send something over 100kb in size on binary, then the connection will be closed with close code [1009: Too Big](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4).